# Two tubes (infinite right circular cylinders) $A$ and $B$ of equal radii $3$ cross at the angle $90°$

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

Two tubes (infinite right circular cylinders) $A$ and $B$ of equal radii $3$ cross at the angle $90°$ (i.e. their axial lines cross at that angle). What is the volume of the intersection of $A$ and $B$?

I figured it should be equal pi*r**2**2*r but just to cross check.

Comment: While searching for duplicates, I overlooked that [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Two-tubes-infinite-right-circular-cylinders-A-and-B-of-equal-radii-3-cross-at-the-angle-90-degrees-i-e-their-axial-line-QTN_2881752.htm&ved=2ahUKEwjE7Z7BhpbrAhVYXSsKHWbLAmQQFjACegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1QypvS5w3PUGgGp4cIW960) site, too, has an answer which matches same as yours (which doesn't makes sense at least to me pi*r**2**2*r). Is this coincidence?

Comment: Please type MathJax that makes some sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid#:~:text=A%20Steinmetz%20solid%20is%20the,equal%20radius%20at%20right%20angles.&text=The%20intersection%20of%20two%20cylinders,cylinders%20is%20called%20a%20tricylinder.